# Burndown chart not showing on taskboard header in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, burndowncharts

In the past few days our company is experiencing a problem with the burndown chart which is part of the task board header. Currently we can not see any data for the current sprint.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYOWK.png)

This is valid for the previous sprints as well.
The burndown chart is available in Analytics tab as shown on the picture below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiGBS.png)

What should we do in order to see the burndown chart in the task board header?

Thanks in advance

Viktor Krstevski

We can not find a way how to see the burndown chart again

Comment: Hi, have you checked the browser dev tools? May there are some output on the console.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why, but I've just gone into User Settings, and then gone to Preview Features, and as soon as I turned on New Boards Hubs the chart is once again showing in all my sprint board headers again.

No idea why that is suddenly necessary when it's always worked perfectly for us in the past without having that turned on... but it's a fix for you so hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much  Tasmin Oliver

Comment: With all the features for CI/CD that Azure devops provide, it's a paradox  that the Microsoft Azure Devops development team itself deploy obvious bugs like this to production.